# ThreadPoolExecutor runs slowly

Tags: python, threadpool

I tried to keep running 10 threading instances.

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
                while True:
                    driver = self.GetNewInstance(self.session_id, self.url)
                    executor.submit(self.GET_NAME, driver, self.name, self.try_limits)
```

But new thread is creating very slowly.

How can I make a new thread start right after an instance is stopped?

Comment: If the function mainly executes Python code (not much IO-access and not using a compiled library), there is not much advantage of multithreading over a single thread (for the standard implementation CPython at least).

Answer (score 0):

```
driver = self.GetNewInstance(self.session_id, self.url)
```

Driver takes some time to initialize. You can try pre-initialize drivers before your script, or use asyncio instead of threads to speed up the process.